# Convert JSON many objects to single JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have JSON, with differents levels field, so I want to convert to a single JSON with fields with one level for example:

```
{
  "prop1":"value1",
  "prob2":"value2",
  "prop3": {
     "prop4":"value4",
     "prop5":"value5"
  }
  ... many level fields
}
```

result

```
{
  "prop1":"value1",
  "prop2":"value2",
  "prop4":"value4",
  "prop5":"value5"
  .......
}
```

I'm using Jackson with annotation `@JsonProperty("field")`, I haven't problem wih fields of first level , but I don´t know  how to access field where to into more inside JSON , for this example are `prop4` and `prop5`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[JsonUnwrapped](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) is the annotation to use, it even works for multi-level nesting. For example:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class Sample {

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        SampleClass sample = new SampleClass("value1", "value2", new SubClass("value4", "value5", new SubSubClass("value7")));
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(System.out, sample);
    }

    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=Visibility.ANY)
    public static class SampleClass {
        private String prop1;
        private String prop2;
        @JsonUnwrapped
        private SubClass prop3;

        public SampleClass(String prop1, String prop2, SubClass prop3) {
            this.prop1 = prop1;
            this.prop2 = prop2;
            this.prop3 = prop3;
        }
    }
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=Visibility.ANY)
    public static class SubClass {
        private String prop4;
        private String prop5;
        @JsonUnwrapped
        private SubSubClass prop6;
        public SubClass(String prop4, String prop5, SubSubClass prop6) {
            this.prop4 = prop4;
            this.prop5 = prop5;
            this.prop6 = prop6;
        }

    }
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=Visibility.ANY)
    public static class SubSubClass{
        private String prop7;

        public SubSubClass(String prop7) {
            this.prop7 = prop7;
        }
    }
}
```

will generate

```
{"prop1":"value1","prop2":"value2","prop4":"value4","prop5":"value5","prop7":"value7"}
```

Comment: Great !!! , thanks a lot for the information , is a great alternative with JsonUnwrapped  , but  need  will make  a second implementation class with  anottation mentioned , the next question is  exist anyway generate all unwrapped json fields, only modifying  mapper  features ?

Comment: If you don't want to modify your original class, you can use the Mixin mechanism: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations. And no, there is no such feature that you can activate on `ObjectMapper` that will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the @JsonUnwrapped annotation. More information at http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonUnwrapped.html