# How to access JSON subfield using @JsonProperty annotation?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need transform json in another diferent json , im using @JsonProperty annotation for  change name fields JSON result , but i dont know  access fields encapsulate in differents json level for example :

```
{  "prop1" : "value1",
   "prop2" : "value2",
   "prop3" : {
     "prop4" : "value4",
     "prop5" : {
        "prop6" : "value6"
     } 
  }
}
```

json result

```
  { 
    "prop1_new_name":"value1",
    "prop4_new_name":"value4",
    "prop6_new_name":"value6"  
  }
```

Comment: Although you can use `@JsonUnwrapped` for some amount of flattening, perhaps you should re-consider approach itself: why are your POJOs so different from JSON? Do they have to be? Data-binding is designed for cases where two match -- if not, separate transformations often work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"prop3" would be a Map in your Java object when deserializing (if you have it properly annotated). Then you can create a custom JsonSerializer to output your expected result.

To create your custom JsonSerializer, you can follow this guide: http://dev.sghill.net/2012/04/how-do-i-write-jackson-json-serializer.html

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a continuation of your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654208/convert-json-many-objects-to-single-json-using-jackson). So, in addition of using `@JsonUnwrapped` as explained in the answer, you need to add `@JsonProperty` on the field in the class where it is declared. Modifying the previous answer with `@JsonProperty` gives you this:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class Sample {

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        SampleClass sample = new SampleClass("value1", "value2", new SubClass("value4", "value5", new SubSubClass("value7")));
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(System.out, sample);
    }

    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=Visibility.ANY)
    public static class SampleClass {
        private String prop1;
        private String prop2;
        @JsonUnwrapped
        private SubClass prop3;

        public SampleClass(String prop1, String prop2, SubClass prop3) {
            this.prop1 = prop1;
            this.prop2 = prop2;
            this.prop3 = prop3;
        }
    }
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=Visibility.ANY)
    public static class SubClass {
        @JsonProperty("prop4_new_name")
        private String prop4;
        private String prop5;
        @JsonUnwrapped
        private SubSubClass prop6;
        public SubClass(String prop4, String prop5, SubSubClass prop6) {
            this.prop4 = prop4;
            this.prop5 = prop5;
            this.prop6 = prop6;
        }

    }
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=Visibility.ANY)
    public static class SubSubClass{
        @JsonProperty("prop7_new_name")
        private String prop7;

        public SubSubClass(String prop7) {
            this.prop7 = prop7;
        }
    }
}
```

With this as a result:

```
{"prop2":"value2","prop5":"value5","prop7_new_name":"value7","prop4_new_name":"value4","prop1_new_name":"value1"}
```