# Use jackson annotation JsonUnwrapped on a field with name different from its getter

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class like:

```
class Car {
    private Engine myEngine;

    @JsonProperty("color")
    private String myColor;  

    @JsonProperty("maxspeed")
    private int myMaxspeed;

    @JsonGetter("color")
    public String getColor()
    {
        return myColor;
    }

    @JsonGetter("maxspeed")
    public String getMaxspeed()
    {
        return myMaxspeed;
    }

    public Engine getEngine()
    {
        return myEngine;
    }
}
```

and Engine class like

```
class Engine {
    @JsonProperty("fueltype")
    private String myFueltype;

    @JsonProperty("enginetype")
    private String myEnginetype;

    @JsonGetter("fueltype")
    public String getFueltype()
    {
        return myFueltype;
    }

    @JsonGetter("enginetype")
    public String getEnginetype()
    {
        return myEnginetype;
    }
}
```

I want to convert the Car object to JSON using Jackson with structure like

```
'car': {
   'color': 'red',
   'maxspeed': '200',
   'fueltype': 'diesel',
   'enginetype': 'four-stroke'
 }
```

I have tried answer provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654208/convert-json-many-objects-to-single-json-using-jackson) but it doesn't work for me as field names are different then getter

I know I can use @JsonUnwrapped  on engine if field name was engine. But how to do in this situation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

provide `@JsonUnwrapped` and `@JsonProperty` together:

```
@JsonUnwrapped
@JsonProperty("engine")
private Engine myEngine;
```

Answer (score 1):

You shall use the [`@JsonUnwrapped`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) as follows in the Car class for the desired JSON object:

```
class Car {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Engine myEngine;

    @JsonProperty("color")
    private String myColor;  

    @JsonProperty("maxspeed")
    private int myMaxspeed;
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but this is not working. It creates a engine object in json

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution here would be to use `@JsonValue` annotation over the `myEngineType` attribute in your `Engine` class, it will only serialize this attribute instead of the whole `Engine` object.

So your code would be like this:

```
class Engine {

    @JsonProperty("fueltype")
    private String myFueltype;

    @JsonValue
    @JsonProperty("enginetype")
    private String myEnginetype;

}
```

You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17583175/3669624) for more details.